# Fullscreen a running application from the terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, fullscreen

I'm trying to pull a prank on a friend. I have a shell script that continuously cats a C source code file so make it look like the terminal is "hacking" something. The next thing I would like to do is have the script make the terminal full screen.

Is there anyway in the default terminal app to make a window full screen based off of a PID or some other identifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use applescript to send the <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> shortcut:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "F" using {command down, control down}
end tell
```

You can use the `osascript` command to execute applescripts.

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot about sending fake key strokes. Now off to do something funny. Mwahahah